# Using pendrive as flash back in win 10

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I want win 10(64 bits). I have already win 10(32bits) on my pc.I know I need to do a clean install but I don't have DVD so i will use my pendrive

So I want to know if it would delete my file
In the pendrive. If yes, after the installation, can I delete the win 10 iso and put other files in my pendrive

Comment: The only way to migrate from a 32-bit Windows installation to a 64-bit installation is to format the drive.  *How you save your files is entirely up to you though.*  The creation of the bootable drive likely will format, so place your personal files on it, after you create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating bootable installation media using most tools, all data on the pen drive will usually be deleted. In theory it should be possible to just add the installation files and make it bootable without deleting anything, but that's more complicated than using any of the available ready to use wizards, like the *Windows Media Creation Tool*. If you use one of these tools, the drive contents will be deleted and usually can't be restored later on.

Of course you can later reuse the pen drive for whatever you want later on, making it bootable is just a question of modifying some "header" information in the MBR. If you reformat it, everything is just as if you'd buy it new.

Easiest solution to your problem would be buying an extra pen drive. You don't need a big one, 8 GB will be more than enough.